# Covert word document to XSL-FO using Java

Tags: java, pdf, ms-word, xsl-fo

I am trying to covert a word document to pdf using java. 'word to XSL-FO to pdf' is the approach i am looking at.

In this approach to do 'word to XSL-FO', is there any open source api available? or can you please guide me with steps for implementing it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What version of Word document are you converting?

RenderX has [**WordML2FO**](http://www.renderx.com/tools/word2fo.html) stylesheets publicly available that can convert Microsoft's WordprocessingML documents to XSL FO (XSLFO).

> These stylesheets were prepared by
>   RenderX's development team and
>   Microsoft for general use. They are
>   used to convert documents in
>   Microsoft's WordprocessingML XML
>   vocabulary into documents in the W3C's
>   XSL FO (XSLFO) vocabulary.

Answer (score 0):

I totally think that using just a stylesheet is not the way to go because there are too many things you will miss (like resolving styles, drawingml/vml used for the graphics inside a docx/word2003 document, etc).
Try this [code sample](http://ecrion.com/Products/XFRenderingServer/SampleCode.aspx) and move from there. Also to note is that if you generate your Word 2003/2007 using Microsoft's API, the structure of it may not be correct all the time unless you make all the required function calls.

Answer (score 0):

docx4j (open source, Apache license) can do this for you.

See the docx4j Getting Started guide for further details.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try [Docmosis](http://www.docmosis.com) or [JODConverter](http://www.artofsolving.com/opensource/jodconverter) to do the conversion as long as you can install OpenOffice somewhere.  They work on many platforms and can be Java controlled.